# libedit ignores editrc file in Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, haskell

I'm trying to get ghci (Haskell's interactive command line) to handle Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right arrows properly rather than showing garbage like this:

```
Prelude> 1;5D1;5C
```

At the bottom of [this bug report](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2606), it says:

> For the standard ghci with editline,
>   you should add the following to your
>   .editrc file:
>
> ```
> bind "\e[1;5D" vi-prev-word
> bind "\e[1;5C" vi-next-word
> ```

I tried adding that to `~/.editrc`, but nothing changed.  [A MySQL bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=49967) tells us that libedit ignores the editrc file on Linux because it doesn't have the `issetugid()` system call, and it looks like MySQL has its own workaround for the issue.

Does anyone know how to either:

1. Get libedit to acknowledge `~/.editrc`
2. Get GHCi to handle Ctrl+Arrow correctly